# How to set up an optional host parameter in Symfony router?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, router

I would like to set up optional host parameter in Symfony router. I try it on localhost:8000 and if I call en.localhost:8000 it works but as I remove the first lang parameter it does not match the route. Route is defined in route.yaml file:

```yaml
blog-index:
    path:       /blog/{page}
    host:       "{lang}.localhost"
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::index
    defaults:
        lang: 'en'
        page: 1
    requirements:
        lang: 'en|sk'
        page: '\d+'
```

PHP code looks like:

```
public function index(Request $request, $lang = 'sk', $page = 1)
{
    return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
        'route' => $request->attributes->get('_route'),
        'route_params' => $request->attributes->get('_route_params'),
        'page' => $page,
        'locale' => $lang,
    ]);
}
```

If I run `http://localhost:8000/blog` the error message says:

> No route found for "GET /blog".

The [example in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#sub-domain-routing) use `default` so I think it should run also with optional `lang` param. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you cleared cache? `rm -rf var/cache/*`?

Comment: Yes I did. Is there any other way to have lang param optional but not at the end of the url?